# how to build an artificial neural network with scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, neural-network

I am trying to run an artificial neural network with scikit-learn.

I want to run the regression, get the model fit results, an generate out of sample forecasts.

This is my code below. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
# Import required libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sklearn
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
```

#import the data

```
df=pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\Action\Downloads\Python\Practice_Data\sorted_data v2.xlsx")
```

#view the data

```
df.head(5)
```

#to drop a column of data type

```
df2=df.drop('Unnamed: 13', axis=1)
```

#view the data

```
df2.head(5)
```

Import necessary modules

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from math import sqrt
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
```

describe the data

```
df.describe().transpose()


target_column = ['public health care services'] 
predictors = list(set(list(df.columns))-set(target_column))
df[predictors] = df[predictors]/df[predictors].max()
df.describe().transpose()
```

set the X and Y

```
X = df[predictors].values
y = df[target_column].values
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, random_state=40)
print(X_train.shape); print(X_test.shape)
```

import MLP Classifier and fit the network

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
mlp = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(8,8,8), activation='relu', solver='adam', max_iter=500)
mlp.fit(X_train,y_train)
predict_train = mlp.predict(X_train)
```

set up the MLP Classifier

```
mlp = MLPClassifier(
    hidden_layer_sizes=(50, 8),
    max_iter=15,
    alpha=1e-4,
    solver="sgd",
    verbose=True,
    random_state=1,
    learning_rate_init=0.1)
```

import the warnings
import warnings
from sklearn.exceptions import ConvergenceWarning

```
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=ConvergenceWarning, module="sklearn")  
predict_test = mlp.predict(X_test)
```

to train on the data I use the MLPClassifier to call the fit function on the training data.

```
mlp.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

after this, the neural network is done training.

after the neural network is trained, the next step is to test it.

print out the model scores

```
print(f"Training set score: {mlp.score(X_train, y_train)}")
print(f"Test set score: {mlp.score(X_test, y_test)}")

y_predict = mlp.predict(X_train)
```

I am getting an error from below

```
x_ann = y_predict[:, 0]
y_ann = y_predict[:, 1]
```

The error message is

IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed

any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

**`predict` function gives you the `actual class` and since your point can belong to one and only one class (except multi label), it is supposed to be like this only**

What is the shape of your `Y_true_labels`? Might be the case that your labels are `Sparse` and with 2 classes, means `0,1` and since the models is minimising [Log Loss as described here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html#sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.predict) as:

> This model optimizes the log-loss function using LBFGS or stochastic gradient descent.

Also looking at the [predict()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html#sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.predict) it says:

> log_y_probndarray of shape (n_samples, n_classes)
> The predicted log-probability of the sample for each class in the model, where classes are ordered as they are in self.classes_. Equivalent to log(predict_proba(X))

So it means that if probability is `0.3` it means it belongs to class and if it's `0.7` it belongs to class, **ASSUMING** it's binary classification with a threshold set to `0.5`.

What you might be confusing with is the [`predict_proba()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html#sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.predict_proba) function which gives you the probabilities for each classes.

Might be the case. Please post your `X,Y` data shape and type so that we can understand better.

Comment: X.shape

Output: (250, 13)

y.shape
Output: (250, 1)

Comment: Try with `predict_proba` this should give you `250x13` array. Right now it is working in a sense such as: `model.predict(X)` == `np.argmax(model.predict_proba(X)`